# Is discrete quasiconvexity just as good as discrete convexity?

Tags: convex-analysis, computational-complexity, discrete-optimization, searching

(I will frame the discussion below in terms of concavity because it suits the examples I have on hand, but the same arguments apply to convexity, too.)

Consider a function $p(h)$ defined for $h$ on a finite set of integers $\{1, \dots, n\}$. We want to maximize $p$.

##### Discrete concavity

$p$ is called *concave* if the first finite differences are decreasing. That is, $p(h)$ is concave iff

$$p(h+1) - p(h) \leq p(h) - p(h-1), \quad \forall h \in \{2, \dots, n-1\}$$

An example of a discretely concave function is shown below.

[image: concave]

In general, maximizing an arbitrary $p(h)$ is $\mathcal{O}(n)$ because you have to try all the indices. However, concavity means that it suffices to find the *first* index such that the subsequent finite difference is nonpositive (or take $h^* =n$ if all finite differences are positive). This reduces the maximization problem to the following search problem:

> **(SP)** Find the first nonpositive entry of the list $S = \{ p(2) - p(1), p(3) - p(2), \dots, p(n) - p(n-1)\}$.

Since the first $h^*$ entries of the list are nonpositive and the remaining entries of the list are negative, this search can be completed in $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ time using [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

(To formalize the nature of the search, define the list $T$ where

- $T_i = 0$ if both $S_i$ and $S_{i+1}$ are positive,
- $T_i = 1$ if $S_i $ is positive and $ S_{i+1}$ is nonpositive, and
- $T_i = 2$ if both $S_i$ and $S_{i+1}$ are nonpositive

for $i = 1 , \dots, n-1$. The list $T$ sorted in ascending order, so we can use binary search to find the first value $h$ for which $T_h = 1$, or take $h=n$ if all $T_i = 0$, or $h=1$ if all $T_i = 2$.)

##### Discrete quasiconcavity

I made up this term, but it is a natural marriage of discrete concavity and continuous quasiconcavity.

$p$ is called *discretely quasiconcave* if, among the two endpoints of a segment, the one with the lowest function value provides a lower bound for the value of the function on the segment (this follows the definition of quasiconvexity on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function#Definition_and_properties)). That is,

$$p(h) \geq \min\{p(a), p(b) \}, \quad\forall h: a\leq h \leq b$$

where $a, b, h \in \{1, \dots, n\}$.

An example of a discretely concave function is shown below.

[image: quasiconcave]

While the property decreasing finite differences does not necessarily hold for discrete quasiconcave functions, it appears to me from the graph above that the *sign* of the finite differences goes from positive to nonpositive only once--at the optimum **(claim 1)**. This means that we can still use the search problem **(SP)** to find the maximum of a discrete quasiconcave problem in $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ time using the binary search procedure **(claim 2)**.

1. Is claim 1 true? Is there an easy way to prove it?

   My intuition is that just as a discretely concave function can be associated with a continuous concave function $f(h)$ (e.g. a polynomial) that fits its points, the same should regarding associating a continuous quasiconcave function with discrete quasiconcave functions.

   Moreover, by creating an order-preserving mapping $m(h)$ between the indices $h$ of a quasiconcave function and the real numbers, we could "slide the indices around" until $f(m(h))$ is in fact concave. This "shows" that discrete quasiconcave functions are just discrete concave functions under a certain monotone transformation of the domain.

   (Actually, I guess this argument would let you turn any continuous quasiconcave function into a concave function, too, but the nature of the transformation is not obvious.)
2. Is claim 2 true? Has my manipulation of the lists $S$ and $T$ compromised the $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ search time?
3. Has anyone pointed this out before? (I assume so.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **yes.** The easiest way to see that claims 1 and 2 are true is to *start* with binary search, then apply it to the find-max operation in question.

#### Find-1 binary search

In the abstract, a binary search routine solves  the problem of finding the *first* 1 in an $n$-vector $x$ of 0s and 1s when we are *promised* that the vector consists of some number of 0s followed by some number of 1s:

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                       ^
```

To solve this problem, we need only guess an index $i$ and check if $(x_{i-1}, x_i)$ matches the pattern $(0, 1)$. (It is easy to figure out how to handle the boundary case $i=1$.) This check can be done in $O(1)$ time.

In binary search, we start by guessing $i = \lfloor n/ 2 \rfloor$, inspect $(x_{i-1}, x_i)$, and return $i$ if it matches, or else we update the lower or upper bound to $i$ according to whether $(x_{i-1}, x_i)$ is $(0, 0)$ or $(1, 1)$, then call binary search again on this smaller slice of the vector.
Since each nonterminal iteration reduces the number of candidate indexes by a factor of two, the most iterations possible is $O(\log_2 n)$.

#### Find-key binary search

Now, consider the usual "application" of binary search to the problem of finding a certain key $v$ in a sorted list $y$. We can reduce this to the **find-1** problem by "marking" each entry $y_i$ as a $0$ if $y_i < v$ and $1$ if $y_i \geq v$. Suppose $v = 5$:

```
y: 0 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 9 9 9 9 9
x: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                         ^
```

I say "marking," but the important thing to note is that there is no need to actually preprocess the vector as shown above (which would cost $O(n)$ time). Instead, as we perform binary search, we can just inline the check $y_i < v$ by computing $(x_{i-1}, x_i) = (1[y_{i-1} \geq v], 1[y_{i} \geq v])$. (Here $1[\cdot]$ is the so-called "indicator function," which returns 1 if the statement is true and zero otherwise.) So the computation time for "find-key" binary search is still $O(\log n)$.

#### Find-max binary search

Now, consider the OP's question, which is to find the maximum key $w$ in a list $z$ that is increasing up to some point, and then decreasing thereafter. (OP's claim 1 is a direct result of this observation.) In this case, we can again reduce the problem to **find-1** by "marking" each index in the correct way. We know that the target index, and all indices after it, satisfy $z_i \geq z_{i+1}$, and that all indices before the target index satisfy $z_{i-1} < z_i$. So again, we can mark the entries of $z$ as 0 or 1 according to this condition and apply binary search.

```
z: 0 1 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 
x: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                         ^
```

Now our "lazy evaluator" is $(x_{i-1}, x_i) = (1[z_{i-1} \geq z_i], 1[z_{i} \geq z_{i+1}])$. Now, this will require inspecting 3 indices at each iteration rather than the 2 indices from the previous two search problems. But this 3 is constant in the problem size, so (to use a bit of sloppy notation) the only effect it has on the overall computational complexity is to take us from $O(2 \log n)$ to $O( 3 \log n)$, which of course are both just $O(\log n)$ in the end. This establishes the OP's claim 2.

(Again, the way to handle the edge cases $i=1$ and $i=n$ is not hard to figure out.)

#### Generic binary search

If you have followed the discussion above, then it is clear that binary search is an $O(\log n)$ for *any* search problem in which

- the input data is a vector $z$,
- there is a transformation that converts $z$ to $x$, where $x_i = 0$ for indices before the target value and $x_i = 1$ for indices at and after the target value, and
- an arbitrary entry of $x_i$ can be computed in unit time.